# The following system error occurred: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done

Tags: sql-server, ssas, active-directory, visual-studio, cube

While trying to Process a cube i go this error

"Error  133 The following system error occurred:  No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.       0   0"

i know its some user which is available in the roles have been removed from active directory.

the annoying part in this is the error doesn't indicate which user has been removed from active directory, our SQL is setup as windows authentication.

and i have to go and check one by one.

is there a way to identify the user, so i remove it and continue with the processing

Answer (score 2):

from the SQL management studio, connect to Analysis services and go to Roles, under the roles, the user that has been removed from active directory will appear in question marks "????????????????" , remove him and reprocess the cube
[image]

[image]